# How do you first find a class that contains a string and then get the id of the element with that class you just found? Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, jquery-selectors, substring

What I'm trying to do is search a page for an element that has the string 'tab_selected' in the class name. The class name is more than just 'tab_selected'. Its 'tab_selected + the UUID'. The UUID changes so all I really want to search for is if the class name contains 'tab_selected' and then if it does I want to get the ID of that element and set the cookie with that ID. I'm a terrible Noob with javascript so any direction would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear whether you want a jQuery answer or not.

Comment: Why is there an ID in the class name? After re-reading this I see I completely misunderstood it...this isn't where an identifier belongs, why not use an `id`? or a data attribute?

Comment: @nick: because the id may be reserved for other usage and have nothing to do with his UUID. For example if its in a CMS it might be based on the content type and the content entry's primary key.

Comment: @prodigitalson - that's valid, but there's still data attributes, for example `data-uuid="12345"`.

Comment: @nick: thats true, but those are only valid for HTML5 arent they?

Comment: @prodigitalson - technically (by spec) yes, but they cause no issues/conflicts in HTML4

Comment: ooops Nick you're right. the UUID is not in the class. I've missread my own code. That should make it easier then I think...It could have one of a bunch of different classes. Either tab_selected_left_horizontal, tab_selected_right_horizontal, tab_selected_text_horizontal, tab_selected_left_vertical, tab_selected_text_vertical, or tab_selected_right_vertical. So what I could say is if its any one of those classes then get the id...correct?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Thats actually fairly simple with jQ:

```
var sel = '.tab_selected_left_horizontal, .tab_selected_right_horizontal, .tab_selected_text_horizontal, .tab_selected_left_vertical, .tab_selected_text_vertical, .tab_selected_right_vertical';

var ids = $(sel).map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('id');
});
```

---

I would recommend adding an additional class of `tab_selected` without the UUID. This way you can grab all the elements of that class without having to parse class names. So you element might look like this:

```
<div class="tab_selected tab_selected-UUID"></div>
```

This way you can just do `$('.tab_selected')`.

Comment: ooops Nick was right. the UUID is not in the class. I've missread my own code. That should make it easier then I think...It could have one of a bunch of different classes. Either tab_selected_left_horizontal, tab_selected_right_horizontal, tab_selected_text_horizontal, tab_selected_left_vertical, tab_selected_text_vertical, or tab_selected_right_vertical. So what I could say is if its any one of those classes then get the id...correct? Ok so the harder part is actually writing that code...

Comment: see my edit... if youre using jquery it should be easy-peasy... if youre using raw js, itll be a little more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if you're trying to save a cookie from your selected tab jquery can do it for your:

You will need, jquery-ui and a cookie plugin for it, then all you have to do is change your tabs initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
      cookie: {
        // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
        expires: 1
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Cookie plugin is [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Comment: The tabs are generated through coldfusion and I'm not sure how what is currently written in coldfusion could work with jquery-ui. I'm just trying to take what is currently output and work with that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was much more simple than I was making it. Thanks everyone for your help! Here was my test and it worked perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab_selected_text_horizontal").attr("id");
var title = $(".tab_selected_text_horizontal").attr("id");
alert(title);
        });
```